# dotnet test only test projects on solution

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, continuous-integration, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017 and Dotnet Core 2.0 SDK I have a solution with several projects. Some of these are test projects and some are source projects.

I can run `dotnet test` in the root solution direction and it will try to discover tests in all projects of the solution.

However, the source projects do not have tests and so an error is shown for these.  The tests all run and pass except the exit code of the process is 1. This means our CI build fails.

Is there any way to have it only run on the test projects of the solution? They are in a test directory, both on file system and a solution directory but I can't find any way to filter them.

I have written a Powershell script to run it for each item in the test folder however our CI server is using Linux and Docker image [microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/) so a Powershell script won't run there.

I could write it in Bash but then it won't run on Windows.

The only other idea I had to make a custom docker image for the builds that had both dotnet and powershell.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue without a fix. There are some workarounds listed in the issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/411

Answer (score 2):

Good news, as of right now .NET Core 2.2 has this fixed. Commit: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/pull/1745

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about `dotnet test`, this is the relevant issue:

https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/1129

There's [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/1129#issuecomment-344762968) that suggests this workaround:

1. Adding a `Directory.Build.targets` file in the same directory as the solution, containing:

   ```
   <Project>
     <Target Name="VSTestIfTestProject">
       <CallTarget Targets="VSTest" Condition="'$(IsTestProject)' == 'true'" />
     </Target>
   </Project>
   ```
2. Adding a `after.[YourSolution].sln.targets` file in the same directory as well, replacing `[YourSolution]` in the name with your actual solution name, containing:

   ```
   <Project>
     <Target Name="VSTest">
       <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReference)" Targets="VSTestIfTestProject" />
     </Target>
   </Project>
   ```

In [a later comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/1129#issuecomment-361876629) he mentioned that he [blogged the details of how this works](https://dasmulli.blog/2018/01/20/make-dotnet-test-work-on-solution-files/).

Comment: Very helpful summation! This helped us simplify our CI tasks greatly.